# round the float to next integer in python

Tags: python

I want to convert the float values to next integer such as

```
x=1.1
print(x)
```

should return 2

and it also make 1.9 to 2.

any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: what's wrong with math.ceil?

Answer (score 2):

```
import math
math.ceil(1.1)
# 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import math
x=1.1
print(math.ceil(x))
# 2
```